# Simple syntax highlighting using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

Currently I have an editable div and I want to add *very basic* syntax highlighting. Essentially I want text between * to turn a different color and text in quotes to turn a different color. For example:

input: `"hello" *world*`

output: `<span class='a'>"hello"</span> <span class='b'>*world*</span>`

I'm using Rangy.js library to save and restore the caret position so there's no issues there. However I'm really struggling to turn the input into the output. The big problem I have is ignoring any " and * that are already highlighted.

If anyone could point me in the direction of a basic algorithm or regular expression or something it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
function highlight(text) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i] === '"') {
            var stop = text.indexOf('"', i + 1);
            result.push('<span class="a">');
            result.push(text.substring(i, stop+1));
            result.push('</span>');
            i = stop;
        }
        else if (text[i] === '*') {
            var stop = text.indexOf('*', i + 1);
            result.push('<span class="b">');
            result.push(text.substring(i, stop+1));
            result.push('</span>');
            i = stop;
        }
        else if (text[i] === '<') {
            // Skip simple HTML tags.
            var stop = text.indexOf('>', i + 1);
            result.push(text.substring(i, stop+1));
            i = stop;
        }
        else {
            result.push(text.substring(i,i+1));
        }
    }
    return result.join('');
}
```

**Example:**

```
>>> highlight('foo *bar"baz"qux* "foobar" qux')
"foo <span class="b">*bar"baz"qux*</span> <span class="a">"foobar"</span> qux"
```

---

Or with regular expressions:

```
function highlight2(text) {
    return text.replace(/([*"]).*?\1|<[^<>]*>/g, function (match, ch) {
        // 'match' contains the whole match
        // 'ch' contains the first capture-group
        if (ch === '"') {
            return '<span class="a">' + match + '</span>';
        }
        else if (ch === '*') {
            return '<span class="b">' + match + '</span>';
        }
        else {
            return match;
        }
    });
}
```

The regular expression `([*"]).*?\1` contains the following:

- `[*"]` matches `*` or `"`. (They don't need to be escaped inside `[ ]`).
- `( )` captures the matched string into capture-group 1.
- `.*?` matches anything up until the first...
- `\1` matches the same string as was captured into capture-group 1.
- `|` is "Or". It tries to match the left side, and if that fails, it tries to match the right side.
- `<[^<>]*>` matches simple html-tags. It will not be able to handle attributes with literal `<` or `>` in them: `<a href="info.php?tag=<i>">` (that is bad HTML anyway, but some browsers will accept it.)

In the case when it matches an HTML tag, the `ch` parameter will be `undefined`, and the `else`-branch will be picked.

If you want to add more characters, just put them inside the `[ ]`, and add an if-statement to handle them. You can use any character except `-`, `\` and `]` without escaping them. To add those characters, you need to put another `\` in front of them.

Comment: This fails using this test string:

highlight('look <span class=\"a\">"test"</span>') gives the following:

"look <span class=<span class=\"a\">\"a</span>><span class=\"a\">\"test</span></span>"

Comment: It is not supposed to be applied multiple times. I could update it so it tries to ignore HTML-tags, if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic algorithm is

```
function highlight(myInput) {
  // Split the string into tokens.
  // "[^"]*"    matches a minimal run surrounded by quotes
  // \*[^*]*\*  matches a minimal run surrounded by asterisks
  // ["*][^"*]* matches an unmatched quote or asterisk and the tail of the string
  // [^"*]+     matches a maximal un-styled run
  var tokens = myInput.match(/"[^"]*"|\*[^*]*\*|["*][^"*]*$|[^"*]+/g);

  // Walk over the list of tokens and turn them into styled HTML
  var htmlOut = [];
  for (var i = 0, n = tokens.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var token = tokens[i];
    // Choose a style.
    var className =
        token.charAt(0) == '"' ? "a" : token.charAt(0) == '*' ? "b" : null;
    // Surround in a span if we have a style.
    if (className) { htmlOut.push("<span class='", className, "'>"); }
    // HTML escape the token content.
    htmlOut.push(token.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;"));
    if (className) { htmlOut.push("</span>"); }
  }
  // Join the output tokens.
  return htmlOut.join('');
}


alert(highlight('"hello" *world*'));
```